# Rice’s theorem and recursion theorem

Tags: computer-science, computability

> Prove Rice’s theorem using recursion theorem.

I need some hints as to what must be done about it. Please use Davis' book notation: [Computability, Complexity, and Languages, Second Edition: Fundamentals of Theoretical Computer Science](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122063821).

Comment: cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/rices-theorem-by-recursion-theorem

Comment: I thought that was another question. The other one is deleted now, sorry everyone.

Comment: This is a relatively standard construction - basically any proof of Rice's theorem can be reworked into a proof that uses the recursion theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The recursion theorem says that if you have any program $P$ that transforms programs into programs (i.e. P(Q) is a program), there must be a program $Q$ such that $P(Q)$ behaves exactly like $Q$. From a failure of Rice's theorem, you can build a program that violates this.